# Sharing Chef Server with Apache

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, chef

I have a server that shares multiple web based applications for our entire development team. This server has both chef-server and apache installed. Unfortunately, the nginx server that chef installs likes to answer for all requests on port 80. The problem is that I have a staging site hosted by the apache server named staging.myproduct.com. When I try to access that site the chef api site is served.

Is there a way that I can configure nginx not to behave this way? I just want it to either pass the request to the apache server or only answer if it's a chef relevant uri being requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create one server name based virtual host to each one, one for the chef-server (i.e. `chef.myproduct.com`) and other for `staging.myproduct.com`, so Nginx can forward the request using `proxy_pass` directive to the correct backend.